# can i sync folders with windows and linux?

Tags: sync

I use windows and now ubuntu and want to use ubuntu one to backup and sync files between them both so no matter what OS I use, I have the latest synced files. Is that possible?

Comment: Ubuntu One **cannot backup** your files. If you delete a file from either Ubuntu or Windows. It will get deleted from both as well as from the Ubuntu One server on the web.

Comment: Is this a dual boot system or are you talking of two different computers? In the former case there's an easier solution.

Comment: There's also dropbox, which I find incredibly useful.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is [Ubuntu One client for Windows](https://one.ubuntu.com/downloads/windows/).

Answer (score 1):

I believe it should be possible.

Just install [Ubuntu One](https://one.ubuntu.com/downloads/) on both Windows and Ubuntu.

Say you have a folder `Documents` in Ubuntu and you want it to be synced between Windows and Ubuntu. Then just select Sync Locally for that folder in both the Ubuntu and Windows - Ubutnu One Client.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is. You can install an Ubuntu One client in Widows (just follow the instructions on the Ubuntu One website), log in with your account and start syncing.

Comment: OK, I knew there was a client for windows, I just wanted to make sure I could share the same file in windows and ubuntu.